# how to stop jquery animation when my page is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect

I would like to stop my jquery animation when I open new tab in browser. Every time when I leave my page for a while and I come back after some time, my jquery slider goes crazy and it change slides like insane, because I didn't stop it. Do you have some solution?

Comment: Please post a detailed example along with some relevant code.  I know you already got your answer but this whole thing will be useless to future readers otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read somewhere about this and it's called **animation queue buildup**. Instead of trying to stop animation when opening new tab, put `stop()` just before starting an animation.

This will ensure that previous animation is killed before continuing....

for example:

```
$('.some-selector').stop().slideUp();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: How does using `stop` in this manner help him when _"...I come back after some time, my jquery slider goes crazy..."_?  @user794596, I'm glad you're happy, but the way your question is written, it's unclear how this answer solves anything.  Please update your question so that it makes more sense with this answer.

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    // code to start 
});
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    // code to stop
});
```

With jQUery:

```
$(window).bind('focus', function() {
  // code to start
});
$(window).bind('blur', function() {
  // code to stop
});
```

Comment: [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is the old way.  For jQuery 1.7 and up... [`.on()` is the preferred method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: This solution worked out really well for me. Thanks!